# "CASE WHEN" clause inside SUM

Tags: jpa, jpql, criteria-api, case-when

My table/entity looks like this:

```
*ID* | *Description* | *Error* | *batchId*
  1  | test 111      |    0    | 456
  2  | test 222      |    1    | 456
  3  | test 333      |    0    | 456
  4  | test xxx      |    1    | 458
  5  | test yyy      |    1    | 458
```

I'm trying to select results in this form:

```
batchId | HowManyOK | HowManyErrors 
   456  |     2     |       1
   458  |     0     |       2
```

In JPQL, I tried that:

```
SELECT 
   g, 
   SUM( CASE WHEN g.error = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ok, 
   SUM( CASE WHEN g.error = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ko  
FROM
   GoogleMerchantLog g 
GROUP BY g.batchId
```

But it doesn't compile! It claims an error "The encapsulated expression is not a valid expression." at the SUM.

Maybe some suggestion to solve it using Criteria API?

**No solution?**
I finally resolved mapping a native query :((

Comment: How try with just `CASE WHEN...` without `SUM()` method and make sure using `JPA 2.x` version.

Comment: but... by removing SUM(), I won't have the sum of the group, I will just have 1 or 0?

Comment: @FabioB. did you resolve it

Comment: Unfortunately... no! I went another way, I suppose. I don't remember exactly, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I have just written:

```
@Query("SELECT new be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitValidation(Z.organization, " +
            "Z.documentType, " +
            "Z.language, " +
            "Z.recipientProfil, " +
            "Z.documentDate, " +
            "sum(case when(Z.status = be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.WAITVALIDATION) then 1 else 0 end), " +
            "sum(case when(Z.status = be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.WAITTOSEND " +
            "or Z.status = be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.POSTED " +
            "or Z.status = be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.CREATED " +
            "or Z.status = be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.SENDING) then 1 else 0 end), " +
            "sum(case when(Z.status = be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.SENT) then 1 else 0 end)) " +
        "from Zoomit as  Z " +
        "where Z.organization = :organization " +
            "and Z.status in (be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.WAITVALIDATION," +
            "be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.WAITTOSEND," +
            "be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.POSTED," +
            "be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.CREATED," +
            "be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.SENDING," +
            "be.mteam.zoomit.persistence.vo.ZoomitStatus.SENT) " +
        "group by Z.organization, Z.documentType, Z.language, Z.recipientProfil, Z.documentDate")
List<ZoomitValidation> getValidations(@Param("organization") String organization);
```

It was successfully executed.

Your code:

From:

```
SELECT 
   g, 
   SUM( CASE WHEN g.error = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ok, 
   SUM( CASE WHEN g.error = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS ko  
FROM
   GoogleMerchantLog g 
GROUP BY g.batchId
```

To:

```
SELECT 
   g.batchId, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN (g.error = false) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ok, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN (g.error = true) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ko  
FROM
   GoogleMerchantLog g 
GROUP BY g.batchId
```

Maven:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
```

PS : Did not find a way to use statics import to shorten the ZoomitStatus enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

Case inside sum statement - in JAVA JPA Query (JPQL)

```
public interface MyTableRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTable, UUID> {
    //c.columnName are properties of MyTable class
    // take care of spaces and , caracters
  @Query("SELECT c.userEmail, " +
            " SUM (CASE c.propertyColumn WHEN 'average' then c.valueColumn ELSE 0 END) as average," +
            " SUM (CASE c.propertyColumn WHEN 'percent' then c.valueColumn ELSE 0 END) as percent" +
        
            "FROM MyTable AS c GROUP BY c.userEmail ")
    List<Tuple> selectByPropertyCase();
}
```